# PHP | Templates - Using files as template only

Tags: php, html, parsing, templates, conditional-statements

I'm currently using an own template system where I need to assign variables to their placeholders which will be replaced later. Unfortunately, It's not possible yet to use conditions like if/else directly inside the template. I always have to handle this in PHP and need to assign the final values to the template.

How it currently is in php:
`$template->assign('{content}', ($b ? 'value' : 'value2'))`, and in html: `<div>{content}</div>`

What I want:
`<div><?php echo ($b ? 'value' : 'value2'); ?></div>` or `<div><?php echo ($b ? 'value' : $this->renderAnotherTemplate()); ?></div>`

I could use .php-files or something like that but as far as I remember, the template file name is visible in the url. So I need a way, to read a string from a template file, execute it's php and accessing the current variables I use in the parser ([eval](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php) is dangerous).

Does anyone of you have a good idea, how to do this?

Thank you!

Comment: There is pretty much no reliable way to have a parser run the php code without making it essentially just an eval (e.g. include). Your best best would be to either work out how to use if/else statements in your own way or use an existing template system that does this already. Your own way would be up to you, but you would essentially be writing your own language parsing system.

Comment: @Jonathan Yeah, I already realized that, but I hoped there's another way. :/

Comment: You could work some way to assign a callback function to the placeholder so that it can be evaluated at render.

Comment: Also, eval/include is not great, but really only dangerous if you can't control the files you are rendering. If they aren't user submitted templates, there is nothing wrong with including a php file. It would be just as secure as including any other file on the system, template or not.

Answer (score 0):

Why don’t you just include a PHP file?

`include(‘template.php’)`

You’ll be able to access all the variables inside your template file that are available in the scope where you call include(). You could wrap it within a method on your template object which may also accept variables to be used in your template file.

The other solution would be to pull in a templating language such as blade, twig or smarty. But honestly I’d just go with the simpler include on a small project

Comment: This is essentially the same as eval as it will run all php code in the file, not just the statements OP wants.

Comment: There was no suggestion in the OP that the template files are coming from user input or any other external source, so wheres the harm in running all the PHP code? Only going by the information provided

Comment: I never said they were coming from user input. I agree though, and said that above as a comment to the question. However, they specifically said that eval is evil meaning that they likely don't want to use eval in some way. And my point was that include is essentially nothing more than a wrapper for eval.